# jquery ajaxupload 3.5 plug-in

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am having a little problem with this ajaxupload.3.5.js. When you click on the upload button first time, nothing happens. You have to click on it again to open up the file browser. Is there a way to fix this?

thanks in advance.

http://code.google.com/p/framework-abdh/source/browse/trunk/ABDHFramework/Scripts/ajaxupload.3.5.js?spec=svn228&r=228

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. The upload code needs to be wrapped around : $(function(){ ... } I was attaching this to a button click which didn't work.